# Which non-parametric model / test to use with a mix of quantitative and categorical variables?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, nonparametric

My response variable $Y$, number of nodes, is quantitative discrete (only positive values), while my 2 covariates are $X1$, number of days (quantitative discrete), and $X2$, city (categorical variable with 10 levels).

I only have 10 (independent) observations and the $Y$ variable is definitely not Gaussian, so I have to rule out both parametric regression and ANOVA. The goal is to compare $Y$ among different cities ($X2$) considering also variable $X1$.

Which statistical model or test could I use to explore the influence of my covariates on the response variable and eventually test for significant differences between cities, considering also $X1$ (number of days)?

Comment: Generalized linear models would be the usual approach

Comment: Which generalized model approach would you use?...remember I only have 10 observations so it's not just the 'normality' of data the problem...

Comment: @Glen_b is referring to Poisson regression.  However, with the same number of variables as data, any model will be saturated; this is a real problem for you.

Comment: the lack of data is a problem for any analysis. If you really want to test for differences among cities then even suggesting treating city as something akin to a random effect, perhaps in a hierarchical model seems to not fit with your aim, so I didn't suggest it. So I have no instant solution for your lack of data. The most obvious GLMs to think about would be Poisson and quasi-Poisson, though I'd consider negative binomial, and it might be possible that you actually have something more in keeping with a binomial - there's not enough information about what you're doing for me to guess.

Comment: Ok, thanks gung and Glen_b for your ideas. I guess since I only have 10 observations that I'd need to use a non parametric Poisson regression if at all, since the sample size is too small...the 10 observations correspond to the 10 cities...within which I have a measure of this # of nodes (count data, Y variable), and total # number of days (X1) taken to create this "nodes" (or edits) on a map.